# How to Create a Selenium Test in Visual Studio to run over all the projects?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

I have a generic Selenium Test which needs to run over all projects how would i do that with Visual Studio online? I can get it to work on one project at a test but not sure how to make it so this test can run on all projects?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you need to write the specific Selenium test for the specific project. However if all the projects you mentioned have the same structure/components/features, then you can reuse the Selenium test project for them.

I don't think it's this is applicable if you mean create tests together which want to apply for all the different projects.

You can reference below articles about the Selenium Test in TFS:

- [Get started with Selenium testing in a CD pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/test/continuous-test-selenium?view=vsts)
- [Parallel Testing in a Selenium Grid with VSTS](https://colinsalmcorner.com/post/parallel-testing-in-a-selenium-grid-with-vsts)

Comment: @ashlast Have you resolved the issue? is the answer helpful? If that helps, you could vote it up and if that resolved your issue, you could Accept it as an Answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread